# ansible loop over comma separated list from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I have an environment variable injected by `Jenkins` like:

```
CUSTOMERS="foo,bar"
```

Now i need to loop over these values.
Is there any way to access these values AS items in `ansible`?

Any help including other suggestions how to to solve this is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the environment variable to ansible with `--extra-vars`, but that's only part of the solution, you need to get the string value into a data format that ansible understands.

One straightforward option is to write a simple Python (or your preferred language) script to convert the environment variable to a JSON list and pass the JSON file to ansible as extra vars with `--extra-vars "@customers.json"` (JSON file input is available in ansible 1.3), see [Ansible Variable documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line).

```
import sys
import os
import json

DEFAULT_VAR="CUSTOMERS"

def var_to_json(var_name, list_sep = ','):
  var_dict = {var_name: os.environ[var_name].split(list_sep)}
  return json.dumps(var_dict)

var_name=DEFAULT_VAR
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  var_name = sys.argv[1]
print var_to_json(var_name)
```

The script above could be generalized further (or customized to your situation). I'll have to leave it to you to hook the pieces together in your build environment.

Alternatively, as [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22862246/172599) explains, you can define a custom filter in ansible to process the input value. You could create a filter that converts the variable value to a list, then use the filter in your playbook when referencing the variable (presumably passed in via `--extra-vars`).

Comment: That script generating the json-file works perfectly. Thank you!